# Vue.js cache http requests with axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm developing a PWA with Vue.js.
When the user starts it, some information from another application is needed. For this, i'm using axios:

```
let url = 'url';
axios.get(url).then((response) => {
  callback(response.data)
})
```

it's working fine as long as the user is online. if the network connection is OK, data should be retrieved by the URL, and if there is no internet connection, data should be loaded from cache. How is this possible?

Comment: You can read up on service workers and how to cache using that. https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker

Comment: There's also an old issue on [support for caching get request](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/31).

Comment: browser not caching url with query parameters

Answer (score 19):

You can check out this extension https://github.com/kuitos/axios-extensions

Here is the basic usage example, I hope it helps

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { cacheAdapterEnhancer } from 'axios-extensions';

const http = axios.create({
    baseURL: '/',
    headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' },
    // cache will be enabled by default
    adapter: cacheAdapterEnhancer(axios.defaults.adapter)
});

http.get('/users'); // make real http request
http.get('/users'); // use the response from the cache of previous request, without real http request made
http.get('/users', { cache: false }); // disable cache manually and the the real http request invoked
```

Comment: -1 This adapter library will ignore all caching directives from the data provider and  cache using consumer side configuration (defaults to 5 minutes).  If you have control over the source data/service, then use proper HTTP caching directives.  And especially since the OP mentions PWA, service workers are a much better solution here as they are designed for this exact problem.

Comment: @Phil this would make a great answer if you wanted to expand it with some pointers for simple SW setup. We're dealing with a similar issue grabbing design resources from a CDN via axios and wanting the browser to just cache them like it would a typical image etc

Comment: will it work if query parameters are added to url?