# How to correctly perform API calls in the React web application? How to avoid the error "429 (Too Many Requests)"

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have some React components, when I render them, they perform the corresponding API access via Axios and output data.

As an example, I have a component in which I display a list of tournaments.
How correct is such a request? Sooner or later, if I go to the page where tournaments are displayed ten times, I get the error "429 (Too Many Requests)"...
How can I fix this, how can I render a request once when visiting the site and just cache it and avoid unnecessary repeated requests?

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import classes from "./listTour.module.css";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {URL} from '../../../URL'
import axios from "axios";

const ListTour = (props) => {

    const [cardTour, setCardTour] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getListTournaments = async () => {
            try {
                const tours = await axios.get(`${URL}/tournaments`)
                console.log(tours.data)
                setCardTour(tours.data)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
        getListTournaments()
    }, [])

    return (
        cardTour.map(tour => {
            return (
                <Link key={tour.id} to={`Profile/${tour.name_tour_sort}`}>
                    <div className={classes.cardTour}>
                        <div className={classes.cardTourAdaptive}>
                            <div className={classes.cardTourBanner}>
                                <img className={classes.cardTourBannerImg}
                                     src={`/images/LogoAndBannerTour/${tour.banner_tour}`} alt={`${tour.name_tour}`}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className={classes.nameTour}>{tour.name_tour}</div>
                            <div className={classes.prizePoolTour}>{tour.prize_pool}</div>
                            <span className={classes.DateTour}>{tour.date_tour}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Link>
            )
        })
    );
};

export default ListTour;
```

Comment: put something in `useEffect dependency array` it controls when the effect should run. And anyway you could try using `useQuery` to fetch data from API i hear is magical. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js cache http requests with axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671255/vue-js-cache-http-requests-with-axios) Note that despite the title, there is nothing Vue-specific about the question or its answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a state like:

```
const [loaded,setLoaded] = useState(false)
useEffect(()=>{
  setLoaded(true)
},[])
useEffect(() => {
    const getListTournaments = async () => {
        try {
            const tours = await axios.get(`${URL}/tournaments`)
            console.log(tours.data)
            setCardTour(tours.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    loaded && getListTournaments()
}, [loaded])
```

For caching an API's response, I'd suggest [redux](https://redux.js.org/) or if you want to go with the easier way [react reducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) which is built-in.
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but it didn't help.

After several dozen visits to the tournament page, he issues "429 (Too Many Requests)", and this is a logical outcome, because every time the component is rendered, the API request will be processed again and again...
And that's the problem, I don't need him to make this request every time if the data has not been changed. I need him to take data from the API once and not try to get it again when he re-enters the page.